# How to resume zenity list after picking choice?

Tags: bash, zenity

I have a zenity list whose entries call different scripts. Among them there is a scripts which concatenates all the results from other scripts. I would like to recall this script so I can save what I have done. My problem is that the zenity list disappears after I make my choice. I wonder whether there is an option or a trick to have the list always running so I can call other scripts while one is running.